# Error during downloading PDF File using Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I try to download a PDF file using Spring 5. Below is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/pdf", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> getPDF(ServerHttpRequest httpRequest) 
{
    File file = new File(filepath);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> resource = getResource(file);
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(resource);
}

public ResponseEntity<Resource> getResource(File file) {
   final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());
   headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
   headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
   headers.add("Expires", "0");
   return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF).contentLength(file.length()).body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnDiscard(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Flux;
>
> at
>   org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils.readByteChannel(DataBufferUtils.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils.read(DataBufferUtils.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils.read(DataBufferUtils.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.codec.ResourceEncoder.encode(ResourceEncoder.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.codec.ResourceEncoder.encode(ResourceEncoder.java:40)
>     at
>
> ...

Answer (score 5):

You have an error with your dependencies. You are using incompatible versions of Spring Framework and Project Reactor:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnDiscard(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Flux;

Correct your project setup, you can use [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) to see how a proper setup looks like.